# Strlen() Vs Strcmp for checking empty char array variable

Tags: c++, strcmp, strlen

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char c1[5];
    char c2[5];

    if ( strlen(c1) == 0)
    {
        std::cout<<" c1 empty";
    }

    if (strcmp(c2, "") == 0)
    {
        std::cout<<" c2 empty";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

if ( strlen(c1) == 0) ==> equivalent assembly code ==>

```
lea     rax, [rbp-5]
movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rax]
test    al, al
jne     .L2
```

if (strcmp(c2, "") == 0) ==> equivalent assembly code ==>

```
movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-10]
movzx   eax, al
test    eax, eax
jne     .L3
```

Not able to differentiate assembly code, they almost generate same code in assembly. Which is efficient way of checking array as empty?
Any help or more information will be appreciated.

Comment: `c1[0] == '\0'` might be even quicker. Ensure you are using optimisations before checking the assembly. Gcc seems to compile both your options to `c1[0] == '\0'`: https://godbolt.org/z/TaW8oxbax

Comment: FWIW, `g++` with `-O3` compiles both to a single `cmp BYTE PTR [rsp+6], 0` followed by a jump

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20285/meaning-of-cmp-byte-ptr-ebp-9-0?newreg=96562ed704cd419cb484ba2dbcc38809

Answer (score 0):

C++ has something called the *as-if rule*. Your code has to behave as if `strlen` was called and the result compared to `0`. But that does not mean it has to do *exactly* that.

A common optimization is to inline the call to `strlen`, since it's simple. This is legal, because your C++ can't notice the inlining. Your code behaves *as if* `strlen` was called.

Another common optimization is to eliminate parts of the code that do not matter. E.g. here it doesn't matter whether `strlen` would return 1, 2 or any other non-zero value.

Comment: I got your explanation but still no clue I am getting to decide which one is better out of strlen or strcmp?

Comment: @BuildSucceeded: In this case? A complete don't care. the compiler optimizes both.

Answer (score -3):

## strlen()

strlen() fucntion return number of characters in that string . Starts counting from first character till null character \0 encountered .

## strcmp()

strcmp() function can return 3 different integer variables  --->
a.) Return 0 if both string are identical.
b.) Return integer value greater than 0 if ASCII value of the first not matching character of left
string is greater than that of corresponding character of right string .
c.) Return integer value less than 0 if ASCII value of first not matching character of left string is
less than ASCII value of corresponding character of right string.

Check out this code to see difference --->

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
int main()
{
char c1[5],c2[5];
std::cin>>c1>>c2;
std::cout<<"Length of first string ="<<strlen(c1)<<"\n";
std::cout<<"Value returned by strcmp() ="<<strcmp(c1,c2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp(c2, "") == 0` already does what it's supposed to. See https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: Yes , I am trying to explain the working of both function in short , strcmp() is more efficient as it does not traverse whole array while on other hand strlen() traverse array till end to calculate total length of array .